# History API with jQuery - address bar changes but doesn't refresh divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I've been able to easily use the history.pushState to change the content of my div and have the address bar reflect a fake url.  However, whenever I push the back/forward buttons the url changes back but the content remains the same.  Typing in the url comes up with an error.  It seems I have the first part of the history API down, but need help doing state changes.

I'm a fairly new programmer and trying to build my website in jQuery and keep the code as concise as possible.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li><button class="navButton" id="signUp" href="./content/registration.php" name="registration" title="Registration">Sign Up</button></li>
<li><button class="navButton" id="settings" href="./content/account_settings.php" name="settings" title="settings">Settings</button></li>
<li><button class="navButton" id="about" href="./content/about.php" name="about" title="About">About</button></li>
</ul>

<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // INITIAL CONTENT ON FIRST LOAD
$("#mainContent").load('./content/start.php');

// CODE FROM HISTORY.JS 
(function(window, undefined) {
var History = window.History; 
if (!History.enabled) {
    return false;
}

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() { 
    var State = History.getState(); 
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    });

    // EVENT LISTENER FOR NAVBUTTON CLASS TO REPLACE CONTENT IN MAINCONTENT DIV
$('.navButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pageurl = $(this).attr('name');
    $("#mainContent").fadeOut().load($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn();
    if (pageurl != window.location) {
        history.pushState('', $(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('name'));
        }
    });

})(window);
});
```

I have installed history.js but if I don't need to use it, that would be preferred.  I would love to have this code corrected so the back button refreshes and this works!

Comment: You need to evaluate within your statechange event whether or not the back button has been pressed and then pull the state out of the history object and perform your fadeout/fadein based on the href

Comment: thanks ohgodwhy, how would I do this?  should I add:    'code' window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    History.getState(location.pathname);
});'code'  ?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by adding an if statement under the popstate to compare the url and determine the content loaded in the mainContent div.  Works!.. but discovered my original pushstate is pushing several popstates the more you click the navButtons.  That question is posted [Cannot find where I have a popstate loop creating multiple history entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306364/popstate-loop-creating-multiple-history-entries-but-where)

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    //WHEN BACK/FORWARD CLICKED CHECKS URL PATHNAME TO DETERMINE WHICH CONTENT TO PLACE IN DIV
    if (location.pathname == "/index.php") {
        $("#mainContent").load("./content/start.php");
    } else {
        $("#mainContent").load("./content" + location.pathname + ".php");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Advice: use the built html5 history state, to pass in objects or params or so on...

Action when you are pushing a state into browser:

```
history.pushState('{url:location}', $(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('name'));
```

Action when your clicked back or front using the browser:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.state != null){
              console.log("url to render"+e.originalEvent.state.url)
            }else{
              console.log("nothing in the state, do nothing")
            }
```

Comment: excellent. this works better then what I had plus I don't have to think about the location.pathname all the time.  This still fails though if my "name" attribute in the url is different than the "href" being referenced for the content when clicking the back/forward buttons. for instance the "settings" url  `<li><button class="navButton" id="settings" href="./content/account_settings.php" name="settings" title="settings">Settings</button></li>`  creates a url of "settings" but is actually referencing the account_settings.php. When back button is clicked it returns a 404 error.

Comment: to clarify.. when back button is clicked from a page back TO the setting page. the 404 error is given.  The initial link to the page works fine.

Comment: That is correct, because the history api will not call the page but only change the state of the page. For the content to display properly when click back respective to the url, you need to get the html via javascript or hide the content on the page itself and display via css.

Comment: I have a few ideas of how to handle this.  I'll try them and see what happens.  It seems I may still need the "if" statement to compare the url to the content loaded.  Thanks for the help.